# How can I set a category using the return value of apply() function in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apply, categories

Thank you in advance for reading.

First of all, I am using python 3.7 with pandas 0.23.4 and numpy 1.15.

If I set a categorycal column like df.at[(...), col] = 'category'
it works just fine.

As shown in the example below, if I set a category from the apply() function, the column becomes of 'object' dtype.

How can I set a category using the return value of apply() function in pandas?

```
<pre>
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

phones = [5551234,5551235,5551236,5551237,5551238,5551239,5551240,5551241,5551242,5551243,5551244,5551245,5551246]

dates = ['01/01/2018','01/07/2017','01/01/2017','01/07/2016','01/01/2016','01/07/2015','01/01/2015','01/07/2014', '01/01/2014','01/07/2013','01/01/2013','01/07/2012','01/01/2012']

df = pd.DataFrame({'PHONE': phones, 'DATE': dates})

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')

age_cats = pd.Categorical([], categories=['hot', 'warm', 'cold', 'old', 'ignored'])

df['AGE'] = pd.Series(age_cats)

df.info()
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
RangeIndex: 13 entries, 0 to 12
Data columns (total 3 columns):
PHONE    13 non-null int64
DATE     13 non-null datetime64[ns]
AGE      0 non-null category
dtypes: category(1), datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
memory usage: 501.0 bytes


def get_age(_date):
    if pd.isnull(_date):
        return 'old'

    today = pd.Timestamp.today()
    d = today.day

    if today.month == 2 and d == 29:
        d = 28
    y1 = pd.Timestamp(today.year -1, today.month, d)
    y2 = pd.Timestamp(today.year -2, today.month, d)
    y3 = pd.Timestamp(today.year -3, today.month, d)
    y4 = pd.Timestamp(today.year -4, today.month, d)
    y5 = pd.Timestamp(today.year -5, today.month, d)

    if today &lt _date:
        raise Exception('Future dates mean there is a bug.')
    if y1 &lt _date and _date &lt= today:
        return 'hot'
    elif y3 &lt _date and _date &lt= y1:
        return 'warm'
    elif y5 &lt _date and _date &lt= y3:
        return 'cold'
    else:
        return 'old'

df.at[:, 'AGE'] = df.DATE.apply(get_age)
df.info()

class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
RangeIndex: 13 entries, 0 to 12
Data columns (total 3 columns):
PHONE    13 non-null int64
DATE     13 non-null datetime64[ns]
AGE      13 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 392.0+ bytes
</pre>
```

I added a second AGE2 column of the same categorical as the first.
I used the same function in a loop process and the categoricaal dtype was not overriden.

Am I using the apply() function wrong?

```
df['AGE2'] = pd.Series(age_cats)

for i, r in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[[i],'AGE2'] = get_age(r['DATE'])

df.info()

class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
RangeIndex: 13 entries, 0 to 12
Data columns (total 4 columns):
PHONE    13 non-null int64
DATE     13 non-null datetime64[ns]
AGE      13 non-null object
AGE2     13 non-null category
dtypes: category(1), datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 605.0+ bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you do this the following way using [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) on `Series` object:

```
df['AGE'] = df.DATE.apply(get_age).astype('category', ordered=True, categories=['old', None])
```

Comment: I will try it. I just got back to post that maybe apply() is to blame for the losing categoricals issue.

Comment: Hey buddy. I think the problem is the <open indexing ":">. 

`dates = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp.today(), periods=12, freq='-6M')
years = list(range(2018, 2010, -1)) # 
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : dates})
df['year'] = pd.Series(pd.Categorical([], categories=years))
df['year2'] = pd.Series(pd.Categorical([], categories=years))

df.loc[df.index, 'year'] = df.date.dt.year    # respect categories
df.loc[:, 'year2']        = df.date.dt.year    # overrides categories`

Comment: It may well be. But is the approach I proposed insufficient or am I missing something.

Comment: Yes (because it absolutely works) and no because I am already struggling with performance. Thank you, because it helped anyway!

Comment: @umberto_jr: if I helped you please consider marking the answer as satisfactory (green tick on the left of the answer).